# How to redirect in exppress with data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm using Express 3.4.7 and mongo. I register a new character into my mongo database and then I would like to have my page (route : /game) but I want to get the data of the mongodb (like the _id) of my character.

Here is my code :

```
exports.newGame = function(ip, db){
return function(req, res){
    //req.body return all the field
    if(req.body.name && req.body.class) {
        db.connect(dbconnection, function(err, db){
            if(err) throw err;
            var collection = db.collection('test'),
            insertObj = {
                name : req.body.name,
                class : req.body.class
            };
            collection.insert(insertObj, function(err, data){
                if(err) throw err;
                console.log(data);
                res.render('player/index', data); //Here is my problem
            });
        });
    } else {
        res.render('home/new', {title : 'Donjon & Gradon - New', ip : ip});
    }
}
};
```

I would like to have the /game page and passing data and db after the query to mongo is OK.

I don't know if I am clear.

Can you help me ?

Regards,

Arnaud

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is.

Comment: I would like to pass the data from mongo into my model that I get when I go to the page /game

Comment: have you read up on express routes with parameters? https://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2014/03/13/parameterized-routes-express-js/

Comment: There is no other way than a GET parameter ?